# Different behavior needed if template template parameter is vector

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++14, variadic-templates

We are using one internal c++ library that takes `std::vector` as input however i want to write wrapper function that should be able to accept `std::vector`, `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` but when input passed to this wrapper function is `std::vector` itself i don't want to copy that in temporary vector so is there any way to avoid this unnecessary copy.

Sample Reference code will explain this issue with more clarity :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
void print(const std::vector<int>& argVec)
{
    for(auto elem:argVec)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }

}
template<template<typename...>class VecOrSet>
void wrapper(const VecOrSet<int>& input)
{
    //How to avoid this temporary vector if input argument is vector itself
    std::vector<int> temp(input.begin(),input.end());
    print(temp);
}
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};  
  std::set<int> s{4,5,6};
  std::unordered_set<int> us{7,8,9};
  wrapper(v);
  wrapper(s);
  wrapper(us);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: print is something i can't control as that corresponds to library function written by some other team

Comment: Does your `print` really take `argVec` by non-`const` reference? If it does, to what extent (if any) can you guarantee that it won't modify the vector being passed in?

Comment: my bad it was just a sample, actual library function takes const and i corrected this sample also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

```
template<>
void wrapper(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    print(input);
}
```

Or just add another overload.

```
void wrapper(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    print(input);
}
```

Or use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

```
template<template<typename...>class VecOrSet>
void wrapper(const VecOrSet<int>& input)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<VecOrSet<int>, std::vector<int>>) {
        print(input);
    } else {
        std::vector<int> temp(input.begin(),input.end());
        print(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't specialize, overload.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for reminding; I'll keep it because specialization is also a valid solution for this case.

Comment: If constexpr seems to be C++17 stuff and adding overload or doing specialization is some thing that i want to avoid because actual function is not as simple as wrapper but +1 for suggesting this simple and elegant approach

Comment: @Kapil *adding overload or doing specialization is some thing that i want to avoid* Don't have a special version for arrays then, your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be initialize `temp` passing through another function: `getIntVect()`, with a generic version

```
template <typename VoS>
std::vector<int> getIntVect (VoS const & input)
 { return { input.cbegin(), input.cend() }; }
```

that copy the `input` in a `std::vector<int>`, and a specific version for `std::version<int>`

```
std::vector<int> const & getIntVect (std::vector<int> const & input)
 { return input; }
```

that return a const-reference to the input (that is: avoid the copy)

So, using `decltype(auto)`,

```
template<template<typename...>class VecOrSet>
void wrapper(const VecOrSet<int>& input)
{
   decltype(auto) temp { getIntVect(input) };

   print( temp );
}
```

`temp` is a reference to `input`, when `VecOrSet` is `std::vector`, or a copy of `input`, otherwise.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP is dubious

> I think this line `decltype(auto) temp{getIntVect(input)};` will call copy constructor of vector if input is vector

This is true for `auto temp{getIntVect(input)};`, as pointed by T.C. (thanks!). Not for `decltype(auto) temp{getIntVect(input)};`

Try compiling and running the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
 {
   A ()
    { std::cout << "- default constructor" << std::endl; }

   A (A const &)
    { std::cout << "- copy constructor" << std::endl; }

   A (A &&)
    { std::cout << "- move constructor" << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename T>
A foo (T const &)
 { return {}; }

A const & foo (A const & a)
 { return a; }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << "--- 000" << std::endl;
   A a0;
   std::cout << "--- 001" << std::endl;
   auto           a1 { foo(a0) };
   std::cout << "--- 002" << std::endl;
   decltype(auto) a2 { foo(a0) };
   std::cout << "--- 003" << std::endl;
   decltype(auto) a3 { foo(0) };
   std::cout << "--- 004" << std::endl;
 }
```

I get (from g++ and clang++) this output

```
--- 000
- default constructor
--- 001
- copy constructor
--- 002
--- 003
- default constructor
--- 004
```

As you can see, `auto a1 { foo(a0) };` call the copy constructor of `A` (because `auto` become `A` and `A a1 { foo(a0) };` cause the the copy of the value returned by `foo()`) but `decltype(auto) a2 { foo(a0) };` doesn't call contructors (because `decltype(auto)` become `A const &` and `A const & a2 { foo(a0) };` simply link `a2` to `foo(a0)` (so to `a0`).

Comment: `auto` makes a copy anyway.

Comment: @T.C. - I ever make this sort of stupid errors: is `decltype(auto)` the way to solve this problem, right?

Comment: @max66 I think this line decltype(auto) temp{getIntVect(input)}; will call copy constructor of vector if input is vector

Comment: @Kapil - you're right for `auto temp{getIntVect(input);` (as pointed by T.C.), but `decltype(auto)` is different. See my improved answer for details.

Comment: @max66 Thanks for the explanation and btw dubious seems to be strong word for my statement :)

Comment: @Kapil - sorry... I don't know English very well :(